# How to sign up for the first time in appwrite mbaas?

Tags: mbaas

After installing appwrite for docker on my windows machine i am unable to sign up on the registration page , all i get is an error registration failed try again later, all the docker containers are running , in the mariadb container there is the following line

2020-06-09 23:34:28 8 [Warning] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.20.0.8' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

Answer (score 1):

Installation was not complete had to wait 40 min for installation for complete mariadb setup

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest Appwrite version installed. This issue is usually related to running MariaDB docker container on Windows setups. If this still happens on the latest Appwrite version, restarting the MariaDB container might help.